# Are people with Bipolar Disorder always in a cycle?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, bipolar-disorder

I know that people with bipolar cycle between moods, say, roughly a few times a year, and I know that there's conditions like ultra-rapid cycling. But something I don't understand, particularly with bipolar 2, is if that person is always in a cycle or not? For example, do they have a depressed episode for, say, a month, and then a hypomanic episode for another month, and then life is normal until they have another episode? Or are they always somewhere in an episode?

Comment: Hi Crimson, please, consider including a reference in your question

Comment: I don't really have a reference. I'm just a college student asking for a friend, and the knowledge I've included just comes from my general knowledge. I haven't been able to find an answer elsewhere, so that's why I've asked it here.

Comment: "Approximately 60% of manic episodes occur immediately before a major depressive episode. Individuals with bipolar I disorder who have multiple mood episodes (major depressive, manic, or hypomania) within 1 year receive the speci­fier "with rapid cycling." (Type 1 Bipolar Disorder, DSM-5, pg 130). Approximately 5%-15% of individuals with bipolar II disorder have multiple mood episodes (hypomania or major depressive) within the previous 12 months. If this pattern is present, it is noted by the specifier "with rapid cycling." (Type 2 Bipolar Disorder DSM-5, pg 137). Hope to have been of help.